# CSV missing values

Tags: android, csv, opencsv

I'm using openCSV to read csv file in order to inflate my auto complete for my android app. Although most of values from csv are successfully read and inflated auto complete text view, some of them are "missing." For example, a csv value *"Los Angeles, CA ",LAX* isn't read by the program.

Reading CSV:

```
  public void readCSV() throws IOException {
      InputStream is = this.getAssets().open("airport-codes.csv");
      InputStreamReader ifr = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");

      CSVReader reader = new CSVReader (ifr);
      ArrayList<String> srd = new ArrayList<>();

      while ((reader.readNext()) != null)
      {
          nextLine = reader.readNext();
          Log.i("ArrivalTest", nextLine[0] + "- " + nextLine[1]);
          srd.add(nextLine[0] + " - " + nextLine[1]);

      }
      reader.close();
      autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.originCityAutoComp1);
      adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, srd);
      autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
 }
```

airport-codes.csv:

```
...

"Lorient, France ",LRT
"Los Angeles, CA ",LAX    // Los Angles LAX is in csv file.
"Los Cabos, Mexico ",SJD
...
```

Logcat:

```
...
Longview, TX - GGG
Lonorore, Vanuatu - LNE
Lord Howe Island, NS, Australia - LDH
Lorient, France - LRT
Los Cabos, Mexico - SJD      // Los Angles LAX is missing.
Losuia, Papua New Guinea - LSA
Lourdes/Tarbes, France - LDE
...
```

Comment: Complete guess here, but try checking the line ending characters in your .csv file for the LA entry, and both of it's neighbour entries.

Comment: @PeteB Thank you for the comment. I took your advice and checked line ending characters (used Notepad ++, looked for CR and LF at the end of each entries) but they were properly listed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your while loop is slurping every odd numbered line of data from the CSV file and throwing it away :)

Try this instead:

```
while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) 
{
   Log.i("ArrivalTest", nextLine[0] + "- " + nextLine[1]);
   srd.add(nextLine[0] + " - " + nextLine[1]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you! God, how stupid I was. Now it's so obvious that it was doing reader.readNext() "twice" in the loop and it makes the cursor jumps to every other lines. You saved my day! :)